# Formatting a date when opening a query used as a source for a report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to format the dates correctly for the below code so that the query the fields [effective_date] and [LastUpdateDate] are formatted in the same format. My issue is that my queries and reports are built in the european format but from what I understand, ACCESS wants the American format.  At some point in the code below I need to add something like format(yyyy/mm/dd) but i am not sure where.

```
Private Sub Comando145_Click()

  DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_ValueAddAndWastes01", acViewPreview, , "[Effective_Date] = #" & LastUpdateDate & "#", acIcon

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marchese,

You are right: Jet/Access SQL wants dates in American format.

For your example, use:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_ValueAddAndWastes01", acViewPreview, , "[Effective_Date] = #" & Format([LastUpdateDate],"mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#", acIcon
```

The **"mm/dd/yyyy"** format string will return a date that Access will understand anywhere.

Reference:

[Allen Browne: International Dates in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html)

Comment: You are right! Thank you for the pleasant Learning experience that will not be forgotten!